# Best way to store large numpy arrays in azure

Tags: python, azure, numpy, numpy-ndarray

At the moment I have around 1000 .npz files in blob storage.
for each request I need to fetch around 5-20 of them.
Each .npz file is around 50-400mb.

I've tried standard blob storage. fetch time for 10 files is about 1-2min
I've tried premium blob storage, which for for reason took twice as long.

Is there a better way to store these?
In a database? File share?
How can I increase the response time.

I use ThreadPool in python to fetch each file in parallel.

Comment: A CDN should help and give you much better download throughput - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-large-file-optimization. File size limits apply but i believe it's somewhere around 1.8 GB for Microsoft CDN.

Comment: Can you provide some more details so that community will help you to solve your issues.